# Buttons, ComboBox, TextBox etc. missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to work on Form Applications on Visual Studio 2015 Community.

After I create the project, I click the "Data Sources" and there are supposed to be items like button, checkbox etc.

I don't know what to download or where. I did some search in web about data sources but probably downloaded the wrong thing :/

Is there any link that I can download those UI stuff (button,textbox etc)

Comment: What type of Project you created?  winform or web?  Which Project templates used in creating your project? Unless there are details we can't really help.

Comment: I appreciate the replies. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those UI stuff is called [`ToolBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2381cd09.aspx) and you can view them by clicking `View --> ToolBox` in Visual Studio's menu or by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> as the keyboard shortcut . Also make sure that you are in `yourForm.cs[Design]` not in the code to see the `ToolBox`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is in `Toolbox`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> you will get what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Create new project with asp net web application template
2. Choose web forms
3. In solution browser, open Default.aspx
4. In view menu, choose ToolBox option
5. Drag and drop UI from shown ToolBox to Default.aspx file
6. Begin execution of your project to view the result.